# Finding the Laurent series of complex function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I was faced with a problem finding the Laurent series of complex function in all possible areas at the point $(-2i)$.
So, my function is:
$$f(z)=\frac{2z-3+2i}{(z+2i)^2(z-3)^2}$$
It can be represented as the sum of partial fractions:
$$f(z)=\frac{\frac{3}{13}-\frac{2i}{13}}{(z-3)^2}-\frac{\frac{3}{13}-\frac{2i}{13}}{(z+2i)^2}$$
If I understand correctly, I need to find the Laurent series in the following areas:
$$D_1=\{0<|z+2i|<|3+2i|\}$$
$$D_2 = \{|3+2i|<|z+2i|<\infty\}$$
So, I got something like this:
$D_1$:
$$\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{(z+2i)^{n-1}}{(3+2i)^{n+1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{(z+2i)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{(z+2i)^{n-1}}{(4i)^{n+1}}$$
$D_2$:
$$\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{(3+2i)^{n-1}}{(z+2i)^{n+1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{(z+2i)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{(4i)^{n-1}}{(z+2i)^{n+1}}$$
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The answer is correct, thanks.

Comment: Why are you assuming that there is something wrong in your answers?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it seems strange to me that in the first area all powers by (z+2i) are positive, and in the second all are negative

Comment: Have you double checked your partial fraction decomposition? The current one does [not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282z-3%2B2i%29%2F%28%28z%2B2i%29%5E2%28z-3%29%5E3%29+%3D+%283%2F13-2i%2F13%29%2F%28z-3%29%5E2+-+%283%2F13+-2i%2F13%29%2F%28z%2B2i%29%5E2) seem to be correct. Also, $\frac{1}{(z+2i)^2}$ is the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(z+2i)^2}$ at $z = -2i$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski My mistake, I have the wrong degree at (z-3)  [click](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282z-3%2B2i%29%2F%28%28z%2B2i%29%5E2%28z-3%29%5E2%29+%3D+%283%2F13-2i%2F13%29%2F%28z-3%29%5E2+-+%283%2F13+-2i%2F13%29%2F%28z%2B2i%29%5E2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the region $D_1$, what you wrote about $\frac1{(z-3)^2}$ is just fine. But, again in $D_1$, you simply have that the Laurent series of $\frac1{(z+2i)^2}$ is just $\frac1{(z+2i)^2}$ itself. There is nothing more to add here.